# How to fix Slim 3 PUT,DELETE request not working

Tags: php, httprequest, slim-3

I am trying to implement DELETE and PUT request but I'm having an error. below is my code

```
$app->group('/departments', function () {
   $this->put('/{id}', DepartmentController::class . ':update')->setName('department.update');
   $this->delete('/{id}', DepartmentController::class . ':destroy')->setName('department.destroy');
});
```

When I try to run the code I got this error message

```
Method not allowed. Must be one of: PUT, DELETE
```

Did I miss something here? Thanks

Comment: How did you call your API ?
 It seems that you use a `GET`, and like you defined it could only manage `PUT` and `DELETE` http verbs

Comment: to update the data, I have a form and submit to 'department.update' route name

Comment: Yes but what is the method use in form? Usually, it's a `POST` in form.

Comment: Yes I put `post` method. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: You define that URL with `departments/{id}`, are or `put` (`$this-put` ) or `delete` (`$this->delete`) but not `POST`. So your form can't execute since route for `POST` does not exist

Comment: Should it be $app->put and $app->delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by adding a hidden input method as follows.

```
//Update
<form action="{{path_for('department.update', {'id':department.id})}}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT">
</form>

//Delete
<form action="{{path_for('department.destroy', {'id':department.id})}}" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

and my `route`

```
$app->group('/departments', function () {
   $app->put('/{id}', DepartmentController::class . ':update')->setName('department.update');
   $app->delete('/{id}', DepartmentController::class . ':destroy')->setName('department.destroy');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$app->group('/departments', function () {
   $app->put('/{id}', DepartmentController::class . ':update')->setName('department.update');
   $app->delete('/{id}', DepartmentController::class . ':destroy')->setName('department.destroy');
});
```

Comment: I have these route group on my `/routes/web.php` already. Thanks